When Jesus said "I am the way". Did he refer to halakha?
When Jesus said "יֵשׁוּעַ אָנֹכִי הַדֶּרֶךְ". Did he refer to הֲלָכָה?
John 14:6 ESV

Jesus said to him, “I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me.


Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

Where are you getting your quote of ישוע אנכי הדרך? This is a Hebrew sentence that I’m unaware of any sources attributing this to Jesus

@AviAvraham, there are Hebrew translations of the Greek scriptures. This will be one of them (From John 14:6).

@RayButterworth why quote a translation here then? This board is an English forum

@Avi Avraham and Ray Butterworth, it's my understanding that most scholars believe that Jesus presented his teachings mostly in Aramaic, since it was the most commonly spoken language among ordinary Galileans and Judeans of that time.

אָמַר לוֹ יֵשׁוּעַ׃ ״אֲנִי הַדֶּרֶך וְהָאֱמֶת וְהַחַיִּים. אֵין אִישׁ בָּא אֶל הָאָב אֶלָּא דַּרְכִּי.
ha-Berit ha-ḥadashah (Jn 14:6). (2000). The Bible Society in Israel.

וַיֹּאמֶר אֵלָיו יֵשׁוּעַ אָנֹכִי הִנְנִי הַדֶּרֶךְ וְהָאֱמֶת וְהַחַיִּים לֹא־יָבֹא אִישׁ אֶל־הָאָב כִּי־אִם־עַל־יָדִי׃
Franz Julius Delitzsch. (n.d.). Delitzsch Hebrew New Testament (Jn 14:6).

The Peshitta has אורחא (transliterated into Hebrew alphabet) for ἡ ὁδὸς.  This means the way in the Targums.

Halakha can indeed mean something very close to "the way." It is derived from the verb "to go" or "to walk." The Jewish Encyclopedia explains:

הֲלָכָה is used in the sense of "way of acting," "habit,"
"usage," "custom," and especially "guidance" and the norm of practise...  Sometimes it is used with the meaning of "tradition." ..."Halakah" stands sometimes for the whole legal part of Jewish tradition

So in one sense the answer is yes. Jesus declared himself to be the true embodiment God's law in daily life. He lived what he preached, and taught his disciples to do likewise. However, as John 14 uses the term, this is probably too simple. In this particular context, Jesus uses "way" in the sense of a road or direction. He is the path by which his disciples will reach the Father:

If I go and prepare a place for you, I will come back again and take
you to myself, so that where I am you also may be. 4 Where I am going
you know the way.” 5 Thomas said to him, “Master, we do not know where
you are going; how can we know the way?” 6 Jesus said to him, “I am
the way and the truth and the life. No one comes to the Father except
through me."

Conclusion: In itself, the expression "I am the way" in Hebrew or Aramaic could imply that Jesus is the embodiment of true halakha - that his disciples are to follow his unique understanding and practice of the Law.  This also has implications for the church's frequent use of "The Way" in identifying itself. (Acts 19:23 etc.) But in the context of John 14, the phrase "I am the way" means that Jesus is the path. He is not merely saying "I hold the true tradition of halakha" but "you must come to the Father through me."

+1 @Dan Fefferman, Your point on the translation of halakha weakens my point 1 below, since it's possible that halakha or the equivalent word in Aramaic, was used by Jesus, but traditionally, halakha was derived from the oral version of the Babylonian Talmud. However, Psalms, Proverbs, and Isaiah use the term, "paths" denoting a lifestyle frequently as does the Essene Manual of Discipline.

An excellent question! There are three methods that I can think of for addressing your question about New Covenant halakha:

Linguistic context of the translation: Jesus didn’t speak to the Galileans in Greek, but in Aramaic. The Greek word that the translator chose was hodos, road or path. This Greek word doesn’t directly come from any Aramaic word implying religious devotion, action, ritual, or law. Correction: The words "walk" or "walking" were used frequently in the Essene Manual of Discipline, the words "way" and "path" were also used to describe a lifestyle. The word, "path" indicating a lifestyle was used extensively in Psalms, Proverbs, and Isaiah. These terms therefore did have had existing religious significance to Galileans and Judeans. Per Dan Fefferman's post, according to the Jewish Encyclopedia, halakha is "the way of acting, habit, usage, custom, and especially guidance and the norm of practise." However, Jesus quotes Isaiah in Matthew 15:8,9 ESV in denunciation of extra-biblical halakha elaborations of Torah:


“‘This people honors me with their lips,
but their heart is far from me; in vain do they worship me,
teaching as doctrines the commandments of men.’”

Instead, "the way" is introduced in a new sense in the New Testament.

“Enter by the narrow gate. For the gate is wide and the way is
easy that leads to destruction, and those who enter by it are many.
For the gate is narrow and the way is hard that leads to life, and
those who find it are few.” – Matthew 7:13,14 ESV


And many will follow their sensuality, and because of them the way
of truth will be blasphemed. – 2 Peter 2:2 ESV


Allegorical equivalent: Other usages that are more specific: Jesus often referred to himself as both the way and the gate/door, both a unique entry and a unique lifestyle. As a lifestyle, one can view these teachings of Jesus as a new halakha when taken in context with what Jesus instructed to his disciples:


“As the Father has loved me, so have I loved you. Abide in my love.
If you keep my commandments, you will abide in my love, just as I have kept my Father's commandments and abide in his love. These
things I have spoken to you, that my joy may be in you, and that your
joy may be full. This is my commandment, that you love one another
as I have loved you.” – John 15 9-12 ESV

This passage is absolutely crucial to a correct interpretation, since Jesus himself reveals the substitution of commandments, namely that he himself kept the 613 commandments of Torah perfectly, but then expects his authentic disciples to keep his commandments, primarily to love each other just as he loved them!

Behaviorally: The actions of his disciples in Acts and as described in the letters from the apostles and to the church in Ephesus in Revelation indicate natural (as in a new nature) rather than ritualistic compliance with the commandments of Jesus. The only ritualistic behavior that Jesus presented related to the Passover celebration: his body and his blood in the meal of remembrance that he shared with his disciples as the elemental principles of the New Covenant.

Hope this helps.
